# CentOS yum *.rpm package changelog (not installation changelog)

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, yum, rpm

I just logged into my new rented server and updated openssl because of the heartbleed-bug (http://heartbleed.com).
I updated using

```
yum list openssl
...
Installed Packages
openssl.x86_64                                        1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4                                         @updates
Available Packages
openssl.i686                                          1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7                                         updates
openssl.x86_64                                        1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7                                         updates


yum update openssl
...
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4 will be updated
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
...
...
Running Transaction
Updating   : openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64                                                                     1/2
Cleanup    : openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64                                                                     2/2
Verifying  : openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64                                                                     1/2
Verifying  : openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64                                                                     2/2

Updated:
openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7

Complete!
```

That way I got my openssl updated. But how do you know which bug was fixed in which version?
I tried with

```
yum history package-info openssl
```

but that only tells me the history of the package on my machine. Do details about the **package itself**.

So I googled and found http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/
There I can see the openssl package my system had at installation (in March 2014): *openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64*

The 1st update (same day in March) updated it the version from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/ current of that day (*openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64.rpm*).

Today I updated to *openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7.x86_64.rpm*.

So I know the history of my system.
**My question is: Does CentOS/RedHat provide a changelog for the packages itself (e.g. "Heartbleed bug fixed, see ....")? Is there a page for this?**

Thanks,
Blama

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical tool for managing RPM packages is `rpm`.

To query the Changelog of an RPM package the command would be:

```
rpm -q --changelog openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the changelog of unistalled packages with the `repoquery` command which is part of `yum-utils` package.

```
repoquery -q --changelog httpd | less
```